# How to test promise in mocha

Tags: node.js

We all know when i return a promise in mocha, it will test the promise.

But if it throw a exception in promise, how to tell if the exception is throw. That is to say, if the exception is throw in promise, then the test passes.

```
it("Should not take game code for the same user twice", function (done) {
    return gameGiftManage.takeGameCode(gameGiftId, userId)
        .catch(function (e) {
            expect(e).to.exist;
            done();
        })
})
```

This is the test i used to test exception, but it won't work in some cases.

takeGameCode:

```
takeGameCode: function (giftId, userId) {
    return GameGiftCode.count({gift: giftId, user: userId}).exec().then(function (c) {
        if (c) {
            throw '该用户已经领取过礼包';
        }
    }).then(function () {
        return GameGiftCode.findOneAndUpdate({gift: giftId, user: {$exists: false}}, {user: userId}).exec();
    }).then(function (a) {
        if (!a) {
            throw '礼包领完了';
        } else {
            return a;
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: in your promise.. are you using throw() or reject() ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using throw, use reject when an error occurs in your promise.  That's what its there for.  It triggers the .catch() that you are trying to assert from.

In addition, for the sake of keeping things simple, it's not recommended to just reject() (which is essentially like saying throw undefined).  reject(new Error('something meaningful here') will produce more consistent results and a better test suite everytime.

Heres a great article to go a bit more in depth with some of the whats and whys http://making.change.org/post/69613524472/promises-and-error-handling

edit: now that you posted some context and it looks like this is within the usage of mongoose, their docs have a pretty good example of how to handle errors when using promises.  Instead of using .catch(), a thrown error is passed as the second param into another .then()  see [this link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#promise_Promise-then)

so instead of .catch(), you want

`.then(null, function(error){
  //handle assertion
})`

Comment: Throw a error will also cause `catch` to be called. Even if i use reject, then i still don't know how to test in mocha.

Comment: yeah i saw your edit to the main post.. working on a revision for my comment.. sorry.  playing around with a test first before i revise

Comment: @ccheng i've added a bit from the mongoose docs that may point you in the right direction.  best of luck in getting some consistency in your tests

Comment: I use a modified version of mongoose, so it will also call `catch` when exception happens.

Comment: just shooting from the hip, but instead of throw 'string' have you tried using throw new Error('string') ?